# Getting typescript arrow function to work with reflection (angular project)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this method call:

```
form.myMethod(x => x.fullName);
```

I want inside `myMethod` to extract `fullName` string.

```
export class LobFromBuilder<T>{
    public myMethod(key:(a: T) => void) {
       // 
       var keyName = key.toString().split('.').slice(-1).pop();//this is the BAD way
       }
}

var form = new LobFromBuilder<CustomerEntity>();    
form.myMethod(x => x.fullName);
```

I need something that will work in angular production mod.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD2AnAtgHgCrQKYA8AuWAdgCYzwBGAVlsHgHzQDeAsAFDTQAOiAlgG5gC0CHkE9g0RFjDF4hEAE9oYYMCxQkABUTwcCgFzLCSgLzRCWAO7RtuhQApGAXwA0TaAHMseQ-YD6bpwAlNAmDJzQTkEA3GxsHMgKALLeABbwxPbA5L4+0OghYfkA2gDWWArwAGb5ALpBhiK8hB5M8RyS3gCuiITQ2fYIKAB0KmoaiLZ6IZBGCrHskWxOcazAciLQVUjIoeZWcDuojFtdICAAcmDIWI14zR7Ryl6GhF3I5FiIkXT2MWzrQgQeAgLDDEDwDz2bYjRIpPDpTI4UIMHDDKpnS7XLBBGLQAD0+NO5yuNwBGxBYIhUJhyGGcLSGXsyKKaLAXlxT0JzywbG5n0sYCk5KBlPBkOhO3pyUZSJR0DZXmgACpoAAmTkEolXC4i4Gg8U0qUMhFMlmo0ZeYZ4eCwHg4LCZXF47noBScLAAUUQOkQbCAA)?  Still dangerous, though.

Comment: @jcalz nice, and why is that dangerous? thanks

Comment: The danger is `myMethod()` accepts weird callbacks with no complaint from the compiler, and weird things happen at runtime up to and including throwing exceptions. You only want it to accept functions of the form `x => x[k]`. Once you think about making that type-safe, it pushes you to only allow `myMethod()` to take "known" accessors built with a method like `accessor<K extends keyof T>(k: K) { return (x: T)=>x[k] }`. Then `form.myMethod(form.accessor("fullName"))` would be safe. But if `accessor()` exists, `myMethod()` is useless. Without a strong use case and a [mcve] for it, I'm skeptical.